# Javascript click and mousedown conflicting

Tags: jquery, event-handling, mouseevent, jquery-events

I have a certain scenario where I'm using `click` to insert a div and then `mousedown` on that div for dragging it around. I have bound the `click` to the parent container, and the `mousedown` on the div itself. But when I `mousedown` on the div, it fires the click on the parent as well, hence inserting multiple divs instead of dragging the already added div!

Is there a way to solve this issue? I can't unbind `click`, since I need to add 2 divs using the `click`, and then bind `mousedown` on these.

Update: I'm using `selector.on(event, handler)` type of binding.

Comment: Have you looked at mouseup() function instead of click()?

Comment: This may help you [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: @BrianHoover Checking it out...

Comment: Tried `mouseup`, no luck! Handler for click still gets called on `mousedown`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this way. `event.stopPropagation` does not stop the click event from firing after mousedown. Mousedown and click events are not related to each other.

```
var mousedownFired = false;

$("#id").on('mousedown', function(event) {
    mousedownFired = true;
    //code
});

$("#id").on('click', function(event) {
    if (mousedownFired) {
        mousedownFired = false;
        return;
    }
    //code
});
```

**Update:**

Mouse events are triggered like this:

1. mousedown
2. click
3. mouseup

If mousedown is triggered, the `mousedownFired` variable will be set to `true`. Then in the click event, it will `return` (i.e. not continue processing the click event), and the `mousedownFired` variable will be reset to false, so future click events will fire normally. Not going to consider two mousedown or two click events.

Comment: Thanks, I have already considered using a flag of some sort. But I have to use `click` twice, for appending 2 divs, and have mousedowns over the 2 divs. Will this flag stop the other click as well?

Comment: I tried this, and wallah, it works when I follow these steps: I click on the parent to append one div, then I click again to append the second div, then I use mousedown over the 2, works. But if I click on the parent to append the first div, and drag it, thus firing mousedown, the next click won't work since I have already set the flag to false!

Comment: Does it mean I have to use 2 flags for 2 clicks?

Comment: Can't do man, `Employer policy`! Just the issue is, I don't wan't the mousedown on the child element to propagate to the parent element.

Comment: :) ... ok then check target element(event.target) in mouse down. if
it is child then skip that execution..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23680/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-yogeshwaran)

Comment: are you sure this is how mouse events are triggered? i thought the order was down, up, then click -  `$('body').on('click mouseup mousedown',function(evt){console.log(evt.type)})`

Comment: @lfender6445 is correct - or at least, I just tested in Chrome, and I get mousedown, mouseup, then click.

Answer (score 4):

What you likely want to do is attach the event handlers to the parent container rather than the individual child divs. By doing this, as new children are created, you don't need to add additional event handlers.

For example:

```
$("#parentDiv").on('click','.childDiv',function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
}).on('mousedown','.childDiv',function() {
    // your dragging code
});
```

When you provide a selector to the .on() function, the function passed is called for descendants that match that selector.

Comment: The click event handler is already bound to the parent, whereas the mousedown is bound to the child divs added from the click handler. How will your solution help me in my situation?

Comment: Notice the ".childDiv" being passed to the .on() function. This is different than the selector.on(event, handler) you already had in that rather than the handler being called when the parent is clicked, it is called whenever a descendant of the parent that matches ".childDiv" is clicked, which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'll try this approach as well. For now, the emergency was solved by above solution! Thanks man, +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can use event.stopPropagation().

Example :

```
$("#button").mousedown(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
// your code here
});

$("#button").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
// your code here
});
```

Look at this page http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I tried this, my handler for `click` still gets called on `mousedown`!

Answer (score 0):

```
            var timestamp = 0;
    jQuery('ul.mwDraggableSelect a',element).mousedown(function(event){
        timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    });

    jQuery('ul.mwDraggableSelect a',element).click(function(event){
        var interval = 400;//if a mousedown/mouseup is longer then interval, dont process click
        var timestamp2 = new Date().getTime();
        if((timestamp2 - timestamp)>interval){ return false; }

                    /* your code here */
            });
```