# Mouse event not functioning

Tags: javascript

I have this for loop that is suppose to create cells and add background color, when a mouse event happens but only the click event is functioning. what do you think the problem is? 
The whole purpose of this code is to create a table grid and be able to add color to targeted cells to make a pixel art.

```
const grid = document.getElementById('submit');
const inputH = document.getElementById('inputHeight');
const inputW = document.getElementById('inputWidth');
const table = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
const color = document.getElementById('colorPicker');

grid.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  table.innerHTML = "";
  makeGrid();
  e.preventDefault();
});

//Create Grid
function makeGrid() {

  for (let i = 0; i < inputH.value; i++) {
    let tr = table.insertRow(i);

    for (let j = 0; j < inputW.value; j++) {
      cell = tr.insertCell(j);

      // adding color to cells from the color picker

      cell.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
      });

      cell.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `but only one of the event is functioning` Which one? Post enough code so that there is a [MCVE]

Comment: Probably because you do not see 'mousedown' unless you keep your mouse pressed..

Comment: How do you know only one is working ? You are assigning a color to the background on mouse down, and then assigning *that same color* to *the same background* if the mouse clicked on the element (a mouse click occurs when the mouse pressed then released its button on the same element)

Comment: I know this is jQuery, but the process is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618478/javascript-click-and-mousedown-conflicting

Comment: @CertainPerformance i have added the whole code

Comment: @offwhite it is not jQuery

Comment: @Seblor the grid is made up of several cells, so the event should work on any cell that has not been affected

Comment: even if i change the event to `mouseover` it still doesn't work

Comment: Femi Ogunmokun, I understand that it's not jQuery, but the event sequence is the same - jQuery is just a load of shortcuts to vanilla JS. try this https://jsfiddle.net/asnbf9y1/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can see what's happening if you have a different color for mousedown and click events:

```
cell.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
  });

  cell.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = hoverColor.value;
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/asnbf9y1/10/